# How to modify the scale of a radar chart from percent to numeric values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating radar chart based on [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614). However my data is not given in %. It is given in minutes. The problem is that the scale is automatically converted to %, and I cannot find the place in the code when the data is multiplied by 100.

This is my dataset:

```
      [
        {axis:"AAA",value:2.56},
        {axis:"BBB",value:1.27},
        {axis:"CCC",value:2.01},
        {axis:"DDD",value:2.71}
      ],[
        {axis:"AAA",value:2.28},
        {axis:"BBB",value:1.05},
        {axis:"CCC",value:1.81},
        {axis:"DDD",value:2.30}
      ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not multiplied by 100, rather it is formatted as a percentage in the RadarChart.js:

```
var Format = d3.format('%');
```

The format is applied here for the grid:

```
.text(Format((j+1)*cfg.maxValue/cfg.levels));
```

And here for the mouseover:

```
.text(Format(d.value))
```

Also, the outermost value (maxValue) is set in script.js:

```
var mycfg = {
  w: w,
  h: h,
  maxValue: 0.6,
  levels: 6,
  ExtraWidthX: 300
}
```

To show non percentage data you could redefine the number format, say by not specifying anything:

```
var Format = d3.format("");
```

If you are not interested in number formatting, you could remove references to it altogether. Instead of `Format(d.value)` you could simply use `d.value`. Of course you would have to something simliar for the max value as well.

After deciding how to format or not format numbers, you will still need to reset your maxValue to work with your dataset.

---

Note, if your axis is minutes, d3.format might not be the most appropriate way to format your values. D3.time.format might be better. Either that or you can create a custom function to output the minutes and seconds if desired.